# Android firebase favorite button changes

Tags: java, android, firebase, button, favorites

I have a list. I shoot data using firebase database. I have a favorite button image on my list. When I click the button, favorites are added to the favorite page. When I click the button, the favorite button image changes. But when I scroll up or down on the page or switch to another page, this changed image returns to its original state. What can I do.

Answer (score 0):

The state of the button is not preserved when moving through activities, because the activity object is re-instantiated each time, so in order to fix it, you just make it a static variable.

```
  private static boolean isCandyPressed = false;
```

Then in your onclick() of button,  set it to true. And thus, handle your logic throughout by cheking this variable.
Hope this solves your problem